# Two professors teaching the same course, should they unify their exams?

Tags: exams

Consider an advanced, specialized, undergrad course. Students are divided into two sections. Each section is taught by a different professor. Both professors follow the same syllabus and textbook (or they are expected to do so to a lrage extent). Do you think they must provide the same exams (i.e. students of each section are given the same exam questions)? Or is it enough for the professors to coordinate and share views, suggestions, etc. and each one can have the freedom to write their own exam for their section? What is the policy in your University?

Comment: Are you one of the professors suffering this dilemma? or one of the students hoping for the 'easier" exam?

Comment: I'm a professor not liking my department trying to enforce me to unify my quesions with others for the advanced courses that I teach. I have my own way of teaching, and in physics, most of the advanced (core topics) have more than one approach for teaching. I like to gauge my course depending on the students. One term I might emphasize one approach/technique another team I might empasize another approach. That's why I'm asking about opinios of professors and the policies in your institutions.1

Comment: You might try to formulate a periodic teaching seminar at your department in which such issues can be discussed. I you have graduate students it might be valuable for them to see some different teaching approaches if they are headed for academia.

Comment: Can you reformulate this question so it's not completely opinion-based?  Asking about the pros and cons of various policies is fine on Stack Exchange, but questions that just poll people as to which one they think is better, or what their institution does, are not.

Comment: Hello, I'm not sure how to formulate that, I had a specific and clear point in mind. If this question doesn't follow the policies of this webstite, then please remove it.

Comment: Voting to close as opinion-based; the first question literally begins "Do you think...?"  (Opinions on this point are both strong and divergent within my department.  I am firmly in the "absolutely not" camp.)

Answer (score 1):

For advanced courses, I've never had such a policy imposed or used, but it likely happens. For first year courses, it is common for students to have the same exam, but to take it at the same time and be graded together by the (large set of) TAs. First year Calculus, for example.

But it might be a mistake to give the same exam to different groups at different times or days. It is an invitation to cheat. So, if such a policy were in place, it would seem to be a requirement that a common exam time be made. That may be possible and desirable. Coordination between professors is probably desirable, even if they each use their own questions and deviate a bit.

This is a US view, where grades overall are normally given for somewhat large ranges of achievement. It isn't desirable if a student can do well in one section but would do poorly in the same course taught by another professor. And even using the same exam is no guarantee of equal results if they are graded by people with different philosophies.

---

I'll also note that two such courses may not proceed in lock step for a variety of reasons, such as the teaching skill and/or philosophy of the professor or even differences in the ability of the students in the sections. Even with random selection of students to sections there can be differences and, in some situations, there can be large differences. So, some judgement is needed about how to conduct the exams.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know that in the US professors have a great deal of freedom. I think the education/university system in my country is greatly inspired by the US. But then, there are many different policies and views. Some departments are trying to narrow the range of freedom (like forcing professors of advanced courses and of different sections to unify their exams).

Answer (score 0):

Is there a room where all candidates can sit the same exam?

Two different exams covering the same material with different questions to the same standard does happen.

In fact sometimes I have to do 3 exams for the same course due to room availability and numbers of students...

It is usually the grading criteria that makes the difference, at least that is what I find.

Comment: Actually, these are two different sections taught by two different professros. The course is the same though. So, I'm not really asking about cases where one needs to write different sets of questions. Also, both sections can have their exam at the same time... The issue is, should the two professors write one exam or should each one have the freedom in writing their own -with proper coordination-? And what's the policy in your institute? I'm talking about an advanced and specialized course.. not 10x.

Comment: Define advanced and specialised? But not sure what you don't follow.

Comment: For example, where I teach, we have 101 physics. This course have many sections taught by several professors and taken by many stduents (not necessarly those specialzing in phyics). We coordinate and write one exam for each section. But then consider, 400 physcs (say, electrodynamics 2). At most we have two sections, taught by two professors. The course is advanced and specialized not a general course.

Comment: Correction: I mean "We coordinate and write one exam for all sections" not "each section"..